# How to dynamically store the value of a loop and return it once the for loop breaks?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a code something like this

```
FOR K IN (SELECT E.COLUMN_VALUE
                  FROM TABLE (SELECT CAST(LEAVE_HOLIDAY_CAL_PKG_NEW.GES_LEV_COLUMN_TO_ROWS_FNC(V_CAL_SUBTSR,
                                                                                                   ',') AS
                                          LEV_TABLE_OF_VARCHAR_TYP)
                                FROM DUAL) E) LOOP

    V_CAL_DESC := CASE WHEN K.COLUMN_VALUE = 'W' THEN 'Project Weekend-' || TO_CHAR((V_DATE1 + V_ITERATION), 'Day') WHEN K.COLUMN_VALUE = 'H' THEN 'Holiday' ELSE 'Working day' END;

    IF K.COLUMN_VALUE = 'H' THEN
      FETCH C_HOLIDAY_CURSR
        INTO V_HOLIDAY_ID;

      SELECT H.HOLIDAY_DESC
        INTO V_CAL_DESC
        FROM LEAVE.LEV_NEW_EMP_HOLIDAY_DTLS H
       WHERE H.HOLIDAY_ID = V_HOLIDAY_ID;
    END IF;



    INSERT INTO LEV_CAL_TEMP_TBL
    VALUES
      (IN_PERSON_ID, K.COLUMN_VALUE, V_DATE1 + V_ITERATION, V_CAL_DESC);
    COMMIT;
    V_ITERATION := V_ITERATION + 1;

  END LOOP;


OPEN C_CAL_CURSR FOR
select *from  LEV_CAL_TEMP_TBL;
```

So every time this for loop runs one row is inserted in the table GES_LEV_CAL_TEMP_TBL.

But I wanted to avoid this as this might affect the performance of the system,So is there any way I can store those value somewhere 
and return the same in cursor once the FOR loop ends.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you can use a collection

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit,i dont know much about cursor actually :(

Comment: u can do the processing done by c_cal_cursor inside the same loop instead of using temp table and another cursor

Comment: @psaraj12 but that will replace the value of cursor each time na.

My need is, if every iteration adds one row
and no of iteration is 4
My req is to have all these 4 in cursor

Answer (score 0):

A cursor FOR LOOP is *row-by-row* a.k.a *slow-by-slow* process.

If you must do it in **`PL/SQL`**, then use the **BULK COLLECT** and **FORALL statement**.

- Declare a **collection type**:

For example,

```
TYPE t_lev_cal_temp_tbl IS TABLE OF lev_cal_temp_tbl%ROWTYPE;

l_lev_cal  t_lev_cal_temp_tbl := t_lev_cal_temp_tbl();
```

- **FORALL** insert statement:

For example,

```
FORALL i IN l_lev_cal.first .. l_lev_cal.last
    INSERT INTO lev_cal_temp_tbl VALUES l_tab(i);
```

Comment: Aint there a way to avoid inserting in table ,and directly returning in cursor.

Comment: Kumar But how shall i do the processing ,i don't have to directly insert in table befor that i need to fetch each and every value for FOR loop and based on that value i need to calculate the other three values and then insert them.

Comment: @Thepallav_abhi You could declare a cursor with the select query the way you want to transform the data, and then you need to populate the collection `l_lev_cal` using **BULK COLLECT**. See few examples here http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/plsql/array_processing.html